# Is there a way to programmatically withdraw money from address?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testing

I am trying to write a test using the Truffle framework and for one of the tests I need to send the contract some ether. Is there a way that I can programmatically make a specified ether account send money to the contract?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the `web3.eth.accounts` array (ex: `web3.eth.accounts[0]`). If you are using test-rpc, there will be a set of pre-created accounts that are accessible via that array.

There is a tutorial you could try following: https://citywebconsultants.co.uk/blog/blockchain/introducing-ethereum-development-part-3-testrpc-and-truffle